# LINQ query to a dropdowlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to put a dropdownlist in the aspx view.  The information is in a remote database.  The code is:

```
public List<SelectListItem> ListarCanales()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var tempCanalList = (from rs in DB.C_gestcobcanalvendsem 
                            group rs by rs.GroupName into canales
                            select canales).ToList();


        foreach (var auxCanal in tempCanalList)
        {
            foreach(var canal in auxCanal)
            {
                ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = canal.GroupName, Value = canal.GroupName });
            }
        }

        return ls;
    }
```

to the controller

```
public ActionResult InformeMensual()
    {
        ViewBag.ListaCanales = ListarCanales();

        return View();
    }
```

in the view, i try to do something like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
hello world
/*next whit asp tags*/
Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaCanales));
```

but doesn't work and I tried different ways, any idea?

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  What happens?

Comment: compilation error, dropdownlist is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter `name` cannot be null or empty. Give the appropriate name to your DropDownList.

e.g:

```
Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownList", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaCanales))
```

Thanks!